# How to use default SSL certificate management for C++ gRPC connection on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, certificate, ssl-certificate, grpc

The gRPC C++ sample indicates that I can use default SSL credentials to ensure that the connection is encrypted (based on the device's certificate store for validating server-side certs).  The specific code (from https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) is:

```
// Create a default SSL ChannelCredentials object.
auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(grpc::SslCredentialsOptions());
// Create a channel using the credentials created in the previous step.
auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(server_name, channel_creds);
// Create a stub on the channel.
std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub> stub(Greeter::NewStub(channel));
// Make actual RPC calls on the stub.
grpc::Status s = stub->sayHello(&context, *request, response);
```

Unfortunately, that code does not allow my application to connect to the server.  It only works if I supply the `pem_root_certs` field of `SslCredentialsOptions` to be set to a valid Certificate Authority key (like Baltimore).

Is there a way to make this work the way it does in the sample code so that the device's own certificate store is used to validate the server cert?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gRPC-Objc on iOS, you can set `GRPCCallOptions.transportType` to `GRPCTransportTypeChttp2BoringSSL` to use a ssl channel. To use the device's certificate, you just need to pass it to `GRPCCallOptions.PEMRootCertificates`.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/objective-c/GRPCClient/GRPCCallOptions.h#L135-L149

Comment: I don't think you've answered the question. He specifically mentioned that he does not want to manually pass any certificate and let gRPC figures what's the default certificate to use.